# How can i initialize JsonObject items in DataModel in android

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-json, gson

I want use **Retrofit** for load data from server, and I use **DataModel** for **set** and **get** data.
**My dataModel such as this :** (this is not mine dataModel, jus like this)

```
public class Movie {
    @SerializedName("poster_path")
    private String posterPath;
    @SerializedName("adult")
    private boolean adult;
    @SerializedName("overview")
    private String overview;
    @SerializedName("release_date")
    private String releaseDate;
    @SerializedName("genre_ids")
    private List<Integer> genreIds = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    @SerializedName("id")
    private Integer id;
    @SerializedName("original_title")
    private String originalTitle;
    @SerializedName("original_language")
    private String originalLanguage;
    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("backdrop_path")
    private String backdropPath;
    @SerializedName("popularity")
    private Double popularity;
    @SerializedName("vote_count")
    private Integer voteCount;
    @SerializedName("video")
    private Boolean video;
    @SerializedName("vote_average")
    private Double voteAverage;

    public Movie(String posterPath, boolean adult, String overview, String releaseDate, List<Integer> genreIds, Integer id,
                 String originalTitle, String originalLanguage, String title, String backdropPath, Double popularity,
                 Integer voteCount, Boolean video, Double voteAverage) {
        this.posterPath = posterPath;
        this.adult = adult;
        this.overview = overview;
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
        this.genreIds = genreIds;
        this.id = id;
        this.originalTitle = originalTitle;
        this.originalLanguage = originalLanguage;
        this.title = title;
        this.backdropPath = backdropPath;
        this.popularity = popularity;
        this.voteCount = voteCount;
        this.video = video;
        this.voteAverage = voteAverage;
    }

    public String getPosterPath() {
        return posterPath;
    }

    public void setPosterPath(String posterPath) {
        this.posterPath = posterPath;
    }

    public boolean isAdult() {
        return adult;
    }

    public void setAdult(boolean adult) {
        this.adult = adult;
    }

    public String getOverview() {
        return overview;
    }

    public void setOverview(String overview) {
        this.overview = overview;
    }

    public String getReleaseDate() {
        return releaseDate;
    }

    public void setReleaseDate(String releaseDate) {
        this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    }

    public List<Integer> getGenreIds() {
        return genreIds;
    }

    public void setGenreIds(List<Integer> genreIds) {
        this.genreIds = genreIds;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getOriginalTitle() {
        return originalTitle;
    }

    public void setOriginalTitle(String originalTitle) {
        this.originalTitle = originalTitle;
    }

    public String getOriginalLanguage() {
        return originalLanguage;
    }

    public void setOriginalLanguage(String originalLanguage) {
        this.originalLanguage = originalLanguage;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getBackdropPath() {
        return backdropPath;
    }

    public void setBackdropPath(String backdropPath) {
        this.backdropPath = backdropPath;
    }

    public Double getPopularity() {
        return popularity;
    }

    public void setPopularity(Double popularity) {
        this.popularity = popularity;
    }

    public Integer getVoteCount() {
        return voteCount;
    }

    public void setVoteCount(Integer voteCount) {
        this.voteCount = voteCount;
    }

    public Boolean getVideo() {
        return video;
    }

    public void setVideo(Boolean video) {
        this.video = video;
    }

    public Double getVoteAverage() {
        return voteAverage;
    }

    public void setVoteAverage(Double voteAverage) {
        this.voteAverage = voteAverage;
    }
}
```

**My json is below image :** (this mine json)
[image]

I want add **medium** from **thumbnail_images** into above **DataModel**, but I don't know how can I it?! Thanks all <3

I want add **medium** from **thumbnail_images** into above **DataModel**, but I don't know how can I it?! Thanks all <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your model add:

```
@SerializedName("thumbnail_images")
private ThumbnailImages thumbnailImages;
```

Create the class `ThumbnailImages` and add inside it:

```
@SerializedName("medium")
private Medium medium;
```

And create the class `Medium` with the fields url, width and height.

You can remove the constructor if you want

Comment: For this objects : **thumbnail_images**, **medium** I should another class? can you send me full code? please. because I am amateur and I really need this tutorial

Comment: yes, two new classes. You would have Movie.java, ThumbnailImages.java and Medium.java

Comment: Thanks my friend, I have another question. can you answer to me again? please